# Move Current Piece in JS Tetris

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, tetris

I'm having trouble grabbing the current piece as I program tetris. Right now, when I try to move one tetromino, all of them move. I've been stuck on this problem for a while, and I'd really appreciate some help. Below is a snippet of the code, and I put the whole thing on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L5q6g/

Thank you!

```
//CONTROLS

function controls(e){
tetrominoList.forEach(function(tetromino){

//RIGHT
if(e.keyCode == 39){
    e.preventDefault(); 
        if(tetromino.gravity < 500 - 4*rows && tetromino.x < 3*cols){

                tetromino.x += cols;

    console.log(tetromino.gravity);

        }
    }

//LEFT
if(e.keyCode == 37){
    e.preventDefault(); 
        if(tetromino.gravity < 500 -4*rows&& tetromino.x > -6*cols){
        tetromino.x -= cols;

        }
        }
//DOWN  
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    e.preventDefault(); 
        if(tetromino.gravity < 500 - 4*rows){
        tetromino.gravity += rows;

        }
        }
    });

//CRASH

if(e.keyCode == 32){
    e.preventDefault(); 
        if(tetromino.gravity < 500 - 4*rows){
        tetromino.gravity +=500;

        }
        }

 });
}
```

Comment: How do you determine which is your current tetromino?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue actually isn't really in this function.  You are assigning the eventlistener to every `tetromino` in `tetrominoList`.  So any time you press a button it is going to affect all of them.

Instead you could try adding the event listeners when you create the `tetromino`, and then later removing the listeners on `tetrominoLand`.

Edit:

I see you actually keep track of your last (active) tetromino with `tetrominoID`.  So instead of updating all the pieces in the list `tetrominoList.foreach`, get rid of the foreach and simply create move the last piece

```
var tetromino = tetrominoList[tetrominoID];
```

Working fork http://jsfiddle.net/8pVzp/

Comment: I'm struggling with what the event listener should listen to. Right now, it listens to a function called 'controls', which uses a forEach function. I think the forEach is grabbing all of the tetrominos. I'm not sure how to make the event listener only grab one tetromino. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Get rid of your foreachfunction and see above